# How to edit a non pandas customized data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe

so I made a data frame from an array through class function using python that looks something like this:

```
mylist =    [Item(comic,20.0,male,yes), 
             Item(paint,14.0,male,no), 
             Item(pen,5.0,female,nan), 
             Item(phone case,9.0,nan,no), 
             Item(headphone,40.0,male,yes), 
             Item(coat,nan,male,no),
             Item(comic,15.0,male,yes), 
             Item(nan,15.0,male,no)
             ... and so on]
```

I obtained the data from excels using pandas, but wish not to use its data frame format because I wish to get a bettwe understanding of the class function.
the code for it is below:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.XLSX'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True)
print(df)
array = df.to_numpy().tolist()
print(array)

class Item():
    __name = ""
    __cost = 0
    __gender = ""
    __prime = ""

    def __init__(self, name, cost, gender, prime):
        self.__name = name
        self.__cost = cost
        self.__gender = gender
        self.__prime = prime

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item({self.__name},{self.__cost},{self.__gender},{self.__prime})"

mylist = [Item(*k) for k in array if k[1]]
#print(mylist)
```

the array will look something like this

```
array = [["comic",20,"male","yes"],
         ["paint",14,"male","no"]
         ... and so on]
```

and my list will look like above.

I wish to remove all "Item" where it is missing an element.

Can you give me some advice, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you define "missing an element". What is considered missing? Empty string, `None`, `nan`? Also how do you get access to each property of `Item`? What you have there is not something I can run on my computer. Take a look a `filter` function.

Comment: @tchar I consider empty string as missing. And I have updated the code that I currently have above. Thank you for telling me to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it as follows (also I would not use the class properties in Item, I don't know why you need them in this case)

```py
import math


class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, cost, gender, prime):
        self.__name = name
        self.__cost = cost
        self.__gender = gender
        self.__prime = prime

    def has_all_properties(self):
        return bool(
            self.__name
            and not math.isnan(self.__cost)
            and self.__gender
            and self.__prime
        )

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            f"Item({self.__name},{self.__cost},{self.__gender},{self.__prime})"
        )


mylist = [
    Item("comic", 20.0, "male", "yes"),
    Item("paint", 14.0, "male", "no"),
    Item("pen", 5.0, "female", float("nan")),
    Item("phone" "case", 9.0, "", "no"),
    Item("headphone", 40.0, "male", "yes"),
    Item("coat", float("nan"), "male", "no"),
    Item("comic", 15.0, "male", "yes"),
    Item("nan", 15.0, "male", "no"),
]

filtered = filter(Item.has_all_properties, mylist)
# Optionally cast to to a list if you want to loop
# multiple times over it or add to it
filtered = list(filtered)
for item in filtered:
    print(item)
```